# Creating a Select Input in React with a defaultValue

Tags: reactjs

I'm encountering a weird problem and I have no idea what is going on. I used the exact same code before but now it's behaving differently. Maybe I'm overlooking something. What I want: For the purpose of my question here: I want to render a select input with three options. One of those options is a "disabled defaultValue" option, which is supposed to be a placeholder. The other two options have a value and the select has a value that is a state i'm passing it to.

So I'm rendering the form like so (I'm keeping it short here in order to have a clean look):

```
<Form
  is_expenditure={this.state.is_expenditure}
/>
```

I have the state defined, it's empty. Then I have my Form component like so:

```
class Form extends React.Component{
  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <form>
      <select value={this.props.is_expenditure}>
        <option disabled defaultValue>Ehne mehne Muh</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
)
  }
};
```

And whenever the component renders the option with value=1 is preselected. If I refresh the page with the browser, the select input suddenly has the defaultValue. But whenever I first start up the dev server and look at the form it has a preselected value... even though the state is definitely empty. Has someone an idea? This is really bothersome. I cut it short here but I had several select inputs and they all had preselected the value=1 option. The weird thing was that when I changed the first select input to a value the other select inputs on the page changed to the defaultValue...

EDIT

It seems like the "disabled" part in the option will keeps it from being selected on render. I'm pretty sure this worked before, did a newer react version disallow this? Is there a workaround? All I want is to have a select input with a placeholder basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `disabled` prop. Browser will ignore that option and it cannot be selected that's why the other options got selected by default. You can handle this empty state while saving it to the state

```js
class Form extends React.Component{
  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <form>
      <select value={this.props.is_expenditure}>
        <option defaultValue>Ehne mehne Muh</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
)
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.
What exactly do you mean by "handling the empty state while saving it to the state"? Wasn't it possible before? Is that a recent change that browsers ignore the "disabled"?

Comment: If you pass `disabled` to select and expect the disabled item to be selected by default, it is not possible because the item is 'disabled'. Instead don't pass `disabled` to the item and when the user select that item, handle it.

Comment: Alright, will do! Thanks for the help and clarification.

Comment: Did I answer your question? Or Do you need more clarifications?

Comment: You did. I'm still pretty sure though that it worked like this before, but if I know it doesn't now I can stop wondering about it.

I'm curious: Do you have an explanation for this: When I have several select input fields in my form, all of which have one option that is the defaultValue and all of those have the "disabled" attribute. Why is it that when I change one of those, that all the others jump to their defaultValue?! (Here also every field has a preselected value different from the defaultValue.

Comment: defaultValue is used to specify the default value for the select. disabled is used to disable certain options in select. Both of them can work together achieving their functionality.